# Polymer dom-repeat prevent reusing nodes

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

```
<custom-element>
    <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
            <div>{{item.value}}</div>
        </template>
    </template>
</custom-element>
```

Firstly, we have `data.length == 2`, then I add a new item to the array and change all values. After these changes, we see 3 div blocks, where first and second block are old (binding works fine), and only third block is new. In my case I want to have new subtree without old blocks. How can I achieve that behavior?

Comment: @tony19 I want to rebuild subtree. If you save first div (for example) in variable, then change data array (add one more item) and after these updates you try to check for equality savedDiv with fist div in these subtree, they are equal, but in my case they should NOT be equal. I want to have new nodes, without reusing previously added nodes.

Comment: @tony19 Yes, I want to completely replace the contents of the repeater